# Listener for barcode scanning event

Tags: java, android, barcode

How can I implement a listener in Java for my Android foreground service that can detect barcode scanning event and save a resulting barcode to a text file, or display a message when barcode scanned with the barcode.

I already created a foreground service.
Is it even possible to have a foreground service with a listener which listens to events when other app (warehouse app) scans a barcode?
Our company only needs to additionally to save a barcode with time of scanning to a database.

Comment: Which SDK do you use for scanning?

Comment: You should add more details.

Comment: I think the only way it is possible if the first app that scans make a broadcast signal using sendBroadcast  mechanism.

Comment: @HalilOzel I will add more details when I have the device with android for scanning. So far I experiment only on my smartphone with Android 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it even possible to have a foreground service with a listener which listens to events when other app (warehouse app) scans a barcode?

Generally speaking, no. The other app is unlikely to be making that information available to arbitrary apps like yours, for privacy and security reasons.

If you know the authors of this "warehouse app" or can otherwise communicate with them, you might ask them if they have any sort of SDK or other way of having your app integrate safely and securely with theirs.

Comment: I thought it, but I rather asked. And asked GPT as well and it has similar answer, that the apps are sandboxed and cannot access resources and data from other apps. Thanks a lot reassurance.